# How to generate new wordpress templates?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, templates, frameworks

I need to create different wordpress templates, is there an usefull tool for it ?

Is It possible to create wordpress templates via zend framework?

Answer (score 0):

You have a plugin for using Zend in Wordpress http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/zend-framework/

For creating a new template you should start searching Google. There are plenty of tutorials. One would be this http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/

Comment: this plugin is for wordpress, it's not possible to use Zend Framework as MVC with Wordpress because MVC looks for the controllers, view, models

Comment: I know but probably he would like to use only some of the functions and the whole framework, otherwise he would start developing over Zend from the beginning.